# transmission of value through an Angular service

Tags: angular, service, components

After a few hours of research, I can't manage to pass the values ​​from one component to another through an angular service in order to also centralize the values ​​of all of my components.
below is my code component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RapportService} from '../rapport/rapport.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-nomduprojet',
    templateUrl: './nomduprojet.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./nomduprojet.component.css']
})
export class NomduprojetComponent {
    formData: any = {
        nomduprojet: '' // provide a default value for the input
    };
    constructor(private RapportService: RapportService) {}
    nomduprojet: string = '';
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formData.nomduprojet = this.RapportService.getFormData();
    }
    setFormData(data: any) {
        this.RapportService.setFormData(data);
    }


    getFormData() {
        return this.formData.nomduprojet;
    }

    submit() {
        console.log("formdata" + this.formData.nomduprojet);

    }


}
```

my code services:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import{ HeadingLevel,Packer,Paragraph,TextRun,Document,Alignment,AlignmentType,UnderlineType } from "docx";
import { NomduprojetComponent} from '../nomduprojet/nomduprojet.component';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RapportService {

    formData: any = {
        nomduprojet: ''
    };

    setFormData(data: any) {
        this.formData.nomduprojet = data;
    }

    getFormData() {
        return this.formData.nomduprojet;
    }
}
```

My component 2:

```
public download(): void {
    const nomProjet = this.RapportService.getFormData();
    const doc = new Document({
        sections: [{
            properties: {},
            children: [
                new Paragraph({
                    text: "Promevent",
                    heading: HeadingLevel.TITLE,
                    alignment: AlignmentType.CENTER,

                }),
                new Paragraph({
                    text: "Chantier:" + nomProjet,
                    heading: HeadingLevel.TITLE,
                    alignment: AlignmentType.CENTER,

                }),


                new Paragraph({
                    children: [

                        new TextRun({
                            text: 'Date:...',
                            bold: true,
                        }),
                    ],
                }),
            ],
        }, ],
    });



    Packer.toBlob(doc).then((blob) => {
        console.log(blob);
        saveAs(blob, 'Promevent n°.docx');
        console.log('Document created successfully');
    });
}
```

I do get a value in my `consol.log` submit this.formData.projectname(ProjectNameComponent) but the send on the other components doesn't seem to run as it should

Comment: Also in my app.module my service is well declared in the providers with the import of the service

Comment: FYI your service is provided in root, you don't have to manually provide it somewhere